# What does "feels be" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> She agrees to rescue him, which she feels be ultimately saving
>   herself.

Does it mean "She agrees to rescue him, and she feels that saving him is eventually saving herself"? I don't understand how "feels be" is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's awkward phrasing, but consider it to be an elliptical form of this (still awkward) sentence:

> She agrees to rescue him, which she feels **[to]** be ultimately saving herself.

Alternatively, it could be rephrased as follows:

> She agrees to rescue him, which she feels **would** ultimately **save** herself.

Comment: Can it be: *She agrees to rescue him, which she feels it turns out to be ultimately saving herself.*

Comment: @dan That sound correct to me. Although, also not an entirely natural phrasing.